# Are timed asserts good idea?

Tags: unit-testing, integration-testing

First of all apologies for weird title, but I dont know how to name what I want to talk about so i called it "timed assert".
Basically lets say that one wants to test certain class functionality but that class methods are async(aka for example instance.Start() returns immediately, but private member instance.Mode will change to enum Started after 2 seconds  ). So 
Would something like:

```
MyObject instance; 
instance.start();
// invented function, first part is the normal assert, 3000 is delay  in milliseconds 
timed_assert(instance.GetMode()==MyObject::Mode::Started, 3000);
```

be a good idea?
Please not that implementing timed_assert as a blocking function is trivial (sleep + normal assert), making it nonblocking is beyond my skill lvl, but you are free to consider it as an option if you are sure it can be done.

Comment: Hardcoded timings are never a good idea. By definition they are not deterministic. One option is to poll with a timeout if you are not able to write a blocking function.

Comment: +1 for poll with timeout. Don't forget to write robust teardown logic for the timeout case.

Comment: but cant you have requirements, like within 500 msecs state must change to X, reason: users hate delay :)

Comment: I'm going to assume this is in C#? If so, you might want to take a look at this video at Channel9 about new UnitTesting features in VS2012 (assuming that is a viable option for you?). It includes a section about tesing Async, and precisely your problem: http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/Europe/2012/DEV214

Comment: @Kjartan It is C++, but Ill check out the C9 video just out of curiosity. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you already have your answer in the comments.... "No. Timed asserts are not a good idea."

The sort of requirement you describe "within 500 msecs state must change to X, reason: users hate delay" is not specific enough.

What hardware is the system running on? What load is it under?

This sort of absolute requirement must be specified precisely, and should be considered performance testing rather than unit or integration testing. Your unit/integration tests should run green no matter what test environment you exectute them on. You're not testing your hardware, are you?